# Media streaming on Windows Server 2012 Standard?

Tags: streaming, media, windows-server-2012

On Microsoft's customer operating systems suchs as 7 and 8, they have included an ability to allow other devices to view local content. It's under Network and Sharing Center. Windows Server editions excluding Essentials don't have this.

I wouldn't like to install any third party programs but it seems I have to. The goal is to allow Playstation to stream video and Logitech's Squeezebox to stream music from the server.

What options do I have to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You could install [IIS Media Services](http://www.iis.net/media) which should be able to do local streaming and a whole lot more. I've not tried it myself.

Comment: I tried that but isn't it required to specify an excat path to the video/music file?

Comment: As I said, I haven't used it. It seems its not that easy to use as a home sharing platform.

Answer (score 1):

It seems now that you have to install this from Microsoft.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40837

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's a ps3, for video streaming I would strongly recommend [PS3 Media Server](http://www.ps3mediaserver.org/).

> PS3 Media Server is a DLNA-compliant UPnP Media Server.
>   Originally written to support the PlayStation 3, PS3 Media Server has
>   been expanded to support a range of other media renderers, including
>   smartphones, televisions, music players and more - all of which are
>   listed on the right. Because it is written in Java, PS3 Media Server
>   supports all major operating systems, with versions for Windows, Linux
>   and Mac OS X. The program streams or transcodes many different media
>   formats with little or no configuration. It is powered by MEncoder,
>   FFmpeg, tsMuxeR and AviSynth, which combine to offer support for a
>   wide range of media formats

For streaming to the Logitech Squeezebox I would give [Logitech Media Server](http://wiki.slimdevices.com/index.php/Squeezebox_Server) a shot.

> Logitech Media Server is the server software that powers audio players
>   from Logitech (formerly known as SlimDevices), including Squeezebox
>   3rd Generation, Squeezebox Boom, Squeezebox Receiver, Transporter,
>   Squeezebox2, Squeezebox and SLIMP3. Logitech Media Server is the new
>   name for Squeezebox Server, starting with version 7.7. Before it was
>   known as Squeezebox Server (version 7.4 to 7.6) and SlimServer (before
>   7.4) Logitech Media Server is Open Source Software and written in Perl. Logitech Media Server runs on pretty much any platform that Perl
>   runs on, including Linux, Mac OSX, Solaris and Windows.